# JTable ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, swing, jtable

Why does the following code result in a `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0 >= 0` ?

```
JTable oTable = new JTable();
for (int row = 0; row < table.getRowCount(); row++) {
  for (int column = 0; column < table.getColumnCount(); column++) {
    oTable.setValueAt(table.getValueAt(row, column), row, column);
  }
}
```

Table has been sorted using SortKeys. After SortKeys works, the view in the GUI is updated but the underlying data (model) has not been changed. I need to either change the underlying model or create a new table with the data from the view.

```
DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) table.getModel();
TableRowSorter<TableModel> sorter = new TableRowSorter<TableModel>(model);
table.setRowSorter(sorter);
List<RowSorter.SortKey> sortKeys = new ArrayList<RowSorter.SortKey>();
sortKeys.add(new RowSorter.SortKey(model.findColumn("col title"), SortOrder.DESCENDING));
sortKeys.add(new RowSorter.SortKey(model.findColumn("col title 2"), SortOrder.DESCENDING));
sortKeys.add(new RowSorter.SortKey(model.findColumn("another col title"), SortOrder.DESCENDING));
sorter.setSortKeys(sortKeys); //this should trigger a .sort()
```

I don't know why the model does not update but it doesn't.

Comment: A very confusing question since you appear to have two independent JTable variables, `oTable` and `table`. You should stick with just the oTable variable.

Comment: 1) Do GUI related matters on the EDT.  2) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: and post the stack trace from the exception

Comment: As an aside.  Did I miss something in that entire 6 lines of code?  Why not simply `JTable oTable = new JTable(table.getModel()); //one liner`?

Comment: Because that isn't what I want to do. The model != table view

Comment: What do you mean by "table view"?

Have you tried the following?
`JTable oTable = new JTable(table.getModel(), table.getColumnModel(), table.getSelectionModel());`

That will create a new table with all of the models of your previous table.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using two JTable variables, `oTable`, and `table`, and the `oTable` JTable has 0 columns and 0 rows, but the JTable referred by table probably doesn't. This will result in Java looking for rows and columns that don't exist. Don't mix and match JTable variables this way.

If you want the table and the oTable JTables to hold the same values, simply pass the model over:

```
oTable.setModel(table.getModel());
```

Comment: I'm specifically avoiding using the getmodel. I'd like to copy the jtable view and not the model.

Comment: @user1286505: please clarify what you mean, since the view is pretty much meaningless without the model, and please list all requirements in an edit to your original post. There's nothing worse then our having to extract shifting requirements from you.

Comment: Please don't hijack my thread. Also, my requirements have not changed. I asked why I was getting array out of bounds and he answered that for me. The extra stuff is just stuff I didn't ask.

Answer (score 2):

Your oTable's model is empty.  As a result, index 0 of its row and/or column is not existent, hence the `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: target >= size, 0 >= 0` when you try to set a value at that row and column.

Comment: That is because Table's view has the data and i want to create a table with only that data.

Answer (score 0):

What I had to do was:

```
for(int row=0; row< table.getRowCount();row++)
{
  for (int column = 0; column < table.getColumnCount(); column++) {
  rowData[column] = model.getValueAt(table.convertRowIndexToModel(row), column);
}
 data.add(row, new Vector(Arrays.asList(rowData)));
}
```